# Página em wordpress está sendo redirecionada para o site "oficial do wordpress"

Tags: php, wordpress

Realizei o backup de um site em wordpress para rodar localmente e realizar alguns testes, porém toda vez que clico em `visitar o site` no menu superior sou redirecionado para o site oficial (live).

Já realizei o update da coluna `option_value` na tabela `wp_options`, e até defini as constantes no `wp-config`.

```
define("WP_SITEURL","http://meubackup.dev");
define("WP_HOME","http://meubackup.dev");
```

E ainda continuo sendo redirecionado para o site em produção.

Comment: Já tentou mudar a URL do site nas configurações do wordpress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No painel do Wordpress vá até a aba Configurações -> Geral e insira o link correto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]